# Closing an Angular UI Modal on a SocketIO Event

Tags: angularjs

I've been stuck for a while on this and I'm really not sure what else to do. Basically I have a program that needs to create an Angular UI Modal when there is only one person in a SocketIO 'Room', and once another person comes into that room, the Modal needs to close. The SocketIO events (modalStart) and (modalEnd) are correct, but I'm not sure how to close out of that first modal. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
angular.module('CoderCombatApp.controllers', [])
  .controller('mainCntrl', ['$scope', 'socket', '$modal', function ($scope, socket, $modal) {
    socket.on('join', function (room) {
        socket.emit('init', room);
    });
    socket.on('modalStart', function(){
      $modal({
        template: '../../views/pairing-modal.html',
        show: true,
        keyboard: false,
        scope: $scope
      });
    });
    socket.on('modalEnd', function(){
      //END THAT MODAL ABOVE
    })
}]);
```

Thank you so much!

*ALso one other thing, when the Modal comes into the browser, it basically is freezing up the browser. The GIF inside the Modal doesn't spin and I'm unable to open Dev Tools in chrome. This could be the reason that it doesn't actually ever close...

*Another updated. Looks like the SocketIO join event I have is being triggered twice, which eventually leads to the Modal freezing. Not sure why it's being triggered twice.

Answer (score 1):

Store a reference to the modal so you can close it later. Something like:

```
angular.module('CoderCombatApp.controllers', [])
  .controller('mainCntrl', ['$scope', 'socket', '$modal', function ($scope, socket, $modal) {
    var modalInstance;
    socket.on('join', function (room) {
        socket.emit('init', room);
    });
    socket.on('modalStart', function(){
      modalInstance = $modal.open({
        template: '../../views/pairing-modal.html',
        keyboard: false,
        scope: $scope
      });
    });
    socket.on('modalEnd', function(){
      modalInstance.close();
    })
}]);
```

Call `$modal.open()` to get the modal instance. You don't need the `show: true` option.

According to the documentation at http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/, there is another option to "end that modal above":

```
$scope.$close();
```

The `$close` method is added to the modal's scope.

Comment: Look how they have done at the `$modal` example Javascript code at http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ - they store the reference in a `modalInstance` variable. I will edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: J.Bruni, thanks for the quick reply. I had my code set up that way earlier and it still wasn't working (and I just tried again and sam result). One thing that could be the reason that I failed to mention earlier is that when the Modal comes into the screen, it basically is freezing up the browser. The GIF inside of is doesn't spin and I'm unable to use the Chrome Inspector at this time, it just doesn't open. Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm... seems you ned to call `$modal.open()` to get a modal instance... let me edit the answer once more.

Comment: More findings: `scope.$close` - just added to the answer.

Comment: Hey jBruni, Thanks for taking the time to look into that. Your answer totally makes sense to me after reading the docs, but for some reason the browser doesn't like it. I get the error below. 

TypeError: Object function ModalFactory(config) {
      function Modal(config) {
        var options = angular.extend({ show: true }, $strapConfig.modal, config), scope = options.scope ? options.scope : $rootScope.$new(), templateUrl = options.template;
        etc etc

I think another issue I'm having is for some reason SocketIO is sending the ModalStart multiple times even if only one person connects.